# Why should tickspacing be less than 16384 in UniswapV3?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, uniswapv3

In UniswapV3,the tickSpacing is capped at 16384. The reason provided is:

> to prevent the situation where tickSpacing is so large that TickBitmap#nextInitializedTickWithinOneWord overflows int24 container from a valid tick

After checking the code of [TickBitmap#nextInitializedTickWithinOneWord](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/TickBitmap.sol) , I am unable to understand how this works. For the value of (256 * tickSpacing + the initial tick) to overflow int24, tickSpacing would have to be much larger according to the calculations I made.
How does values above 16384 for tickSpacing cause an overflow?